# add and delete quizquestion and quiz answers

Tags: javascript, html, css

`I can add quiz questions and answers as a list form and delete them like a todo list. But after I added todos, the todos overwrite themselves and are no longer visible and no longer available in the dictionary.

```js
let dictionary = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("dictionary")) || {};
let ran_key;
let obj_keys;

function addQuizQuestion() {
    dictionary[questionforQuiz.value] = answer.value;
    questionforQuiz.value = '';
    answer.value = '';

    localStorage.setItem("dictionary", JSON.stringify(dictionary));
    render();
}


function render() {
    Quizlist.innerHTML = ''; 
    for (let key in dictionary) {
        Quizlist.innerHTML += `
            <li>${key} - ${dictionary[key]}
            <button onclick="deleteQuiz('${key}')">x</button>
            </li>`;
    }
}

function deleteQuiz(key) {
    if (confirm("Möchten sie wirklich diese Frage inkl. Antwort löschen?") == true) {
        delete dictionary[key];
    }
    render();
}

function nextQuizQuestion() {
    obj_keys = Object.keys(dictionary);
    ran_key = obj_keys[Math.floor(Math.random() * obj_keys.length)];
    question.innerHTML = `${ran_key}`;
}

function compare() {
    if (Textfield.value == `${dictionary[ran_key]}`) {
        text.innerHTML = "Richtig!";
    } else {
        text.innerHTML = "Falsch!";
    }
    Textfield.value = '';
    nextQuizQuestion();
}
```

```css
body {
    background-color: lightblue;
    overflow: hidden;
}

.mdl-textfield {
    width: 100%;
}

#Hinzufügen {
    width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://code.getmdl.io/1.3.0/material.indigo-pink.min.css">
    <script defer src="https://code.getmdl.io/1.3.0/material.min.js"></script>
    <body onload="render()">

        <h1>Quizfragen erstellen</h1>
    
        <br>
        <br>
    
    
    
        <form onsubmit="addQuizQuestion();return false;">
            <div class="mdl-textfield mdl-js-textfield mdl-textfield--floating-label">
                <input class="mdl-textfield__input" type="text" id="questionforQuiz">
                <label class="mdl-textfield__label" for="sample3">Quizfrage eingeben...</label>
            </div>
    
            <div class="mdl-textfield mdl-js-textfield mdl-textfield--floating-label">
                <input class="mdl-textfield__input" type="text" id="answer">
                <label class="mdl-textfield__label" for="sample3">Quizantwort eingeben...</label>
            </div>
    
            <button id="Hinzufügen" class="mdl-button mdl-js-button mdl-button--raised mdl-button--colored">
                Hinzufügen
            </button>
    
        </form>
    
        <ul id="Quizlist">
    
        </ul>    
    </body>
```

I can add quiz questions and answers as a list form and delete them like a todo list. But after I added todos, the todos overwrite themselves and are no longer visible and no longer available in the dictionary.

I googled for 3 hours with no results

I would be grateful for any answer.

Comment: *"the todos overwrite themselves and are no longer visible"*: I could not reproduce this.

Comment: I mean that I can delete and add my questions and answers. Until then everything is good. But if I want to add at least 2 or more questions and answers they don't merge with each other, but the first question and answer is replaced and completely deleted from the dictionary.

Comment: I don't understand what you mean. I play around with your program and see nothing unusual. What does "merge" mean in this context? Can you be explicit about what you enter  -- step by step -- what you get and what you expected instead?

Comment: My problem is that when I add things they overwrite themselves and delete themselves from the dictionary. So I press add and a question and answer is added. If I press add again, another question and answer is added and the first one is completely deleted. Should I perhaps send photos so that people can understand it?

Comment: No, please give literal examples of what you enter, and when you press the button, so we have a way to replay your *exact* scenario. Then tell us what you get, and what you expected instead -- literally.

Comment: For example, I enter what is the capital of Spain as the question and Madrid as the answer. then the question and answer come up separately like this: what is the capital of Spain? -Madrid. Until then it's all good but if I enter another question + answer like What's cool? - Program and press add (don't do anything different than before) it deletes what is the capital of Spain? - Madrid and writes What's cool? - Programming. I would have expected him to write down questions and not replace anything.

Comment: That's not what I get when you do this. The first question - answer and the next question - answer are both on the screen.

Comment: How many questions and answers did you try?

Comment: I did exactly as you described in your previous comment. I give up.

Comment: Did you also enter complete sentences?

Comment: It works with two sentences but not with more.

Comment: Sorry, I'm not good at explaining

Comment: I tried several things. Results [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YbFLR.png). So I have to give up on this.

Comment: oh I'm so sorry it's different for me.